# How to echo $i++ in the loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, printing, echo

```
<?          
$count = 0;
$iNew = 0;
$query = new WP_query('posts_per_page=3');      
while(  ($count < 3) && ($query->have_posts()) ) : $query->the_post();
    if (!in_array($post->ID, $ids)){ 
      $ids[] = $post->ID;
      $count++;
      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'art-small-new'  );
    }
endwhile;
?>
```

And in wordpress template-content want to print on screen $iNew as post number :

```
<span class="iNew"><? echo $iNew++; ?></span>
```

But the result looks :

```
<span class="iNew"></span>
```

Where is problem?

Comment: don't use short tags. They're evil.

Comment: Try incrementing `$iNew` then echoing it out.

Comment: You need to read up on [what get_template_part actually does](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) (including the comments). I *think* they answer your question, but I don't have a wordpress install handy to test it out on.

Comment: Apparently you can't pass variables into `get_template_part`. http://keithdevon.com/passing-variables-to-get_template_part-in-wordpress/ has another way to go about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress doesnt proces external php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051870/wordpress-doesnt-proces-external-php-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the variable via [set_query_var](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_query_var/) in Wordpress

```
// When calling a template with get_template_part()
set_query_var('iNew', $iNew++);
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'art-small-new'  );
```

and within the template, you need to extract it via [get_query_var](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/)

```
$iNew = get_query_var('iNew');
```